# Why is the value of (tete->val)=0 And Not 1823

Tags: c

I have created a function that adds an element in the first of a chain with a value. Normally, the value of `tete->Val=0`. Because I did this: `tete = r;`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (){
    struct element{
    int val;
    struct element *suiv;
};
    typedef struct element element;
    element *tete;
void insertion(element *tete,int X){
    element *r;
    r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
    r->val = X;
    r->suiv = tete;
    tete = r;
    }
    tete->val=0;
    tete->suiv=NULL;
     insertion(tete,1823);
     printf("%d",tete->val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're basically asking why `void f(int x) {x=2;} int i=1; f(i); printf("%d",i);` doesn't print 2

Comment: `element *tete` should probably be `element **tete` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct element{
   int val;
   struct element *suiv;
};

typedef struct element element;

void insertion(element **tete, int X) {
   element *r;

   r = malloc(sizeof(*r));
   r->val = X;
   r->suiv = *tete;

   *tete = r;
}

int main(void){
   element *tete;

   tete = malloc(sizeof(*tete));
   tete->val=0;
   tete->suiv=NULL;

   insertion(&tete,1823);
   printf("%d",tete->val);

   return 0;
}
```

Multiple issues:

- Your original code is not even valid C code and doesn't compile.
- in `main`, you declare a pointer to an object of type `element`, but never initialize it. Yet you try to access its member. This is undefined behaviour. Instead you have to allocate memory for that struct with `malloc` and assign the returned pointer to `tete`.
- in `insertion`, you want to make the `tete` pointer from the main function point to the new node. However you dont modify the `tete` pointer from the main function, but the argument `tete` of the `insertion` function. That has no effect on the original `tete` pointer. Instead you need to pass a pointer to the `tete` pointer to the `insertion` function. Then in `insertion` you can modify the pointer the `tete` *argument* points to itself.

Comment: I do Not How To Thank You You Were very helpful ..